# kryo.readObject cause NullPointerException with ArrayList

Tags: java, kryo

I get a NullPointerException when I unserialize an ArrayList object using kryo.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:215)   
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:199)   
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:96)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:22)    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)     
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
```

I can see that StdInstantiatorStrategy creates an ArrayList without calling its constructor leaving one of the fields uninitialized causing the exception.

The documentation says that the no argument constructor should be called first and if none is available, the StdInstantiatorStrategy should be used to do field by field initialization.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With kryo version 2.24, calling

```
kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy());
```

overrides the default instantiator strategy which uses the class no argument constructor if present. The correct way to do this is to call:

```
((Kryo.DefaultInstantiatorStrategy) kryo.getInstantiatorStrategy()).setFallbackInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy());
```

This is explained here https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo

I think this has changed since version 2.21

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar null pointer exception and I needed to add a custom serializer from: https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers

Ex:

```
kryo.register( Collections.EMPTY_LIST.getClass(), new CollectionsEmptyListSerializer() );
```

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem and finally solve it. In my case, I use protobuf object in Spark job. **Spark kryo serializer couldn't serialize/deserialize protobuf object very well**. We can use two methods to solve this problem.

1. Use protobuf default serialize/deserialize method instead of kryo serialize method. For example, you can convert your Spark `rdd[YourProtobufObject]` to `rdd[ByteString]`, use pb`.toByteString()` do the serialize and use `.parseFrom(xxByteString)` do the deserialize.  Actually, this method is not elegant, but it works.
2. Register your own protobuf class to kryo. The details as follows.

- First, add config to `SparkConf`. For example

```
conf.set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.set("spark.kryo.registrator","your.own.registrator.implement.MyKryoRegistrator")
```

- Second, create your own registrator implement. You can use Twitter  opensource Chill project [ProtobufSerializer](https://github.com/twitter/chill/blob/develop/chill-protobuf/src/main/java/com/twitter/chill/protobuf/ProtobufSerializer.java) dependency or [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter/chill-protobuf), and use `ProtobufSerializer` directly. The maven dependency looks like this.

  ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
       <artifactId>chill_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>0.9.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
       <artifactId>chill-protobuf</artifactId>
       <version>0.9.3</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
               <artifactId>chill-java</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
  ```

create your own kryo registrator implement named `MyKryoRegistrator`

```
class MyKryoRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {
  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo): Unit = {
    kryo.register(classOf[YourProtobufObject], new ProtobufSerializer())
  }
}
```

- Third, run again your Spark job, it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Also pay attention to how you create the list, there are ways to create non-modifiable list, which may cause this kind of serialization trouble.

For example popular shortcut in tests `Arrays.asList("a", "b")` can be problematic.

Workaround: `new ArrayList<>(asList("a", "b"))`.